# Arranging the data in a text file using python: group data by month

Tags: python, python-2.7, logic

I have a text file called `data.txt` which contains the following information in it

```
03/05/2016  502
04/05/2016  502
05/05/2016  501
07/05/2016  504
09/05/2016  505
13/05/2016  506
23/05/2016  501
30/05/2016  501
02/06/2016  502
04/06/2016  502
06/06/2016  501
07/06/2016  504
08/06/2016  505
13/06/2016  506
25/06/2016  499
31/06/2016  501
04/07/2016  501
```

I want the output to be like this. This data should be stored in another file named `reslt.txt`
 (UPDATED)

```
03/05/2016 - 30/05/2016  4022
02/06/2016 - 31/06/2016  4020
01/07/2016 - 01/07/2016  501
```

The 3rd column in `reslt.txt` file is sum of values of 2nd column in `data.txt` file.
I am using python 2.7 and i don't know how to achieve this 
please help me out guyz

UPDATE 2

```
03/05/2016  502
04/05/2016  502.2
05/05/2016  501.9
07/05/2016  504.6
09/05/2016  505
13/05/2016  506.1
23/05/2016  501.3
30/05/2016  501.4
02/06/2016  502
04/06/2016  502
06/06/2016  501
07/06/2016  504
08/06/2016  505
13/06/2016  506
25/06/2016  499
31/06/2016  501
04/07/2016  501
```

Comment: What have you written up till now?

Comment: @Quirk Sir I am not understanding what logic that i need to code , in order to achieve this

Comment: Well there are a few things you need to do: 1. Read input files a line at a time. Parse the month from the line. the day doesn't really matter. 2. If the month and year are the same, just keep the sum of the associated integer value.

Comment: For example, you can split each line by whitespace to get two strings: A date string like `03/05/2016` and a decimal data string like `502` which you could cast to an integer. Moreover you can split the date string about the `/` character to get the stings for the day, months and year. As I said earlier, the day seems irrelevant to your case.

Comment: @Quirk sorry sir not understanding it

Comment: do you even know python?

Comment: @Quirk just basics

Comment: @Quirk sir please do help me

Comment: @Quirk sir can i get output atleast like this

Comment: 03/05/2016 - 30/05/2016  4022

    02/06/2016 - 31/06/2016  4020

    01/07/2016 - 01/07/2016  501

Comment: Try stating the problem in English, first.  That first column looks like it might be calendar dates.  It looks like you might be totaling values for each month.  The output looks like it might be 'earliest date in month - last date in month  total for month'.  But I can really only guess.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the output requirement changed a bit! Nevertheless, this should provide enough motivation to smooth out the rough edges.

```
dataStore = {}

# Method to process an input line
def processLine(dateStr, val):
  if dateStr not in dataStore:
    dataStore[dateStr] = val
  else:
    dataStore[dateStr] += val

# Method to read input file line by line
def doStuff(inFile, outFile):
  with open(inFile, 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
      dateStr, val = line.split()

      # cast decimal value to integer
      val = int(val)

      # process the date string to only keep the month and year
      dateStr = dateStr.split('/')
      dateStr = "/".join((dateStr[1], dateStr[2]))

      processLine(dateStr, val)

  # once you are done reading file, generate output
  writeBuf = []
  for key in dataStore:
    writeBuf.append((key, dataStore[key]))
  writeBuf.sort()

  with open(outFile, 'wb') as fp:
    for tup in writeBuf:
      line = '01/'+tup[0]+' - 30/'+tup[0] + '  ' + str(tup[1]) + '\n'
      fp.write(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  inFile = 'data.txt'
  outFile = 'result.txt'

  doStuff(inFile, outFile)
```

You can easily extend this to include the day as well. Simply modify the part where I process the `dateStr`. The `processLine` method would also change.

---

StackOverflow is **not** meant to get others to do your entire homework. Show your current progress and feel free to ask for help with bugs and improvements. Please bear that in mind the next time you ask for help here.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re 
from collections import defaultdict

def sum_months(data_path):
    with open (data_path, 'r') as f:
        rows = f.readlines()
        sumdict  = defaultdict(int)
        for row in rows:
            month = re.findall("/\d{2}/\d{4}", row)[0]
            sum = re.findall("\d+$", row)[0]
            sumdict[month] += eval(sum) 
    return sumdict   

def pad_strings_and_create_rows(sumdict):
    rows = []
    for k, v in sumdict.iteritems():
        rows.append('01' + k + ' - ' + '30' + k + ' ' + str(v))
    return list(sorted(rows))            

def write_result_to_file(results_lst):
    with open('reslt.txt', 'a') as f:
        for row in results_lst:
            f.write(row + '\n')  

write_result_to_file(pad_strings_and_create_rows(sum_months('data.txt')))
```

Comment: ur code dosent work for floating point values...
what changes should i make , soo that it can run for fllaoting point values tooo

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GhOsT\Desktop\q.py", line 25, in <module>
    write_result_to_file(pad_strings_and_create_rows(sum_months('data.txt')))
  File "C:\Users\GhOsT\Desktop\q.py", line 10, in sum_months
    sum = re.findall("\d+$", row)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range